# Basic probability - either event occurs but not both

Tags: probability-theory

I'm taking a graduate course in probability and statistics using [Larsen and Marx, 4th edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131867938) and I'm struggling with a seemingly basic question.

If A and B are any two events, not mutually exclusive: $$P((A \cup B) ^\complement) = 0.6, P(A \cap B) = 0.2$$

What is the probability that A or B occurs, but not both?  Or in other words:  $$P((A \cap B)\ ^\complement \cap (A \cup B)) = ?$$

So far, I've been able to infer the following: $$ P(A \cup B) = 1 - P((A \cup B) ^\complement ) = 1 - 0.6 = 0.4 $$ and $$P((A \cap B) ^\complement) = 1 - P(A \cap B) = 1 - 0.2 = 0.8$$

Can someone kindly give a hint as to how to approach from here?  Am I heading in the right direction?  How should I think about these types of problems in general?  I feel like the text gives you the basic set of axioms to define things but then neglects the showing  of solutions for slightly more complicated examples of compound probability equations such as the above.

Comment: Have you tried drawing a Venn diagram?

Comment: Try finding another expression of $P((A\cap B)^c\cap(A\cup B))$, maybe with Venn diagrams.

Comment: Drawing the Venn diagram should really be the first thing you do in  a situation like this. It makes this problem basically a one line computation. (See Cameron Buie's answer.)

Comment: I guess it wasn't intuitive to me that probabilities would be additive in that sense.  I did draw the Venn Diagram and was tempted but I thought better of it and decided to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Find the probability of $A$ only plus the probability of $B$ only.

Let $x= P(A~ \text{only})$, $y=P(B ~\text{only})$. Then $x +y + 0.2 =0.4$. Thus $x+y= 0.2$

Answer (score 1):

THe probability that at least one of them occurs is $0.4$ and the probability that both occur is $0.2$. Thus, the probability that *exactly* one occurs is $0.4-0.2=0.2$.

Answer (score -1):

$P((A \cup B)\setminus(A \cap B)) = P(A\setminus B) + P(A\setminus B) = P(A) + P(B) − 2P(A \cap B)$
  you will get the answer!

Comment: what is $P((A \cup B)(A \cap B))$?

Comment: @timmbob: There was a backslash in the source text; yagmur intended and tried to write $(A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B)$ as one would expect based on what followed.

Comment: I very much doubt that you meant $A\setminus B$ in both cases.